# How do I force UIBarButtonItem text to a specific color?

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, uibarbuttonitem, uitoolbar

I have a UIBarButtonItem on a navigation bar. When I enter my app, it starts out white (the desired color) and then switches abruptly to a faded out gray color. If I interact with the app and later return to the same view controller, the button returns to the white color. What could be causing this?

[image: bad button]
[image: good button]

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
    {
        [super viewDidLoad];
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.
        UIBarButtonItem *backButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Logout" style:UIBarButtonItemStyleDone target:self action:@selector(handleBack:)];
        [backButton setTitleTextAttributes:[NSDictionary dictionaryWithObject: [UIColor whiteColor]
                                                                      forKey: UITextAttributeTextColor] forState:UIControlStateNormal];
        //[backButton setTintColor: [UIColor whiteColor]];
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = backButton;
        [self.navigationController.navigationBar setBarStyle: UIBarStyleBlack];
        [self populateSpinners];
        isCategoryPicker = true;
        [self.view setTintAdjustmentMode:UIViewTintAdjustmentModeNormal];
    }
```

I've tried setting the tint color at the view level, the toolbar level, and at the button level and nothing seems to be working. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: Is the `Logout` button enabled in any case? It looks like it gets disabled soon after your view controller has appeared. You can try to set the button's titleTextAttributes for that control state:
`[backButton setTitleTextAttributes: ...  forState:UIControlStateDisabled];`.

Comment: The button is enabled and working. I tried the UiControlStateDisabled and it's still going gray on me.

Comment: checkout if the `handleBack:` method is being called using _breakpoints_. The button goes _gray_ when it is clicked and i think this action is being performed somehow.

Comment: Setting tintColor to the UIBarButtonItem does the trick for me.